# Glide scaling issues

Tags: android, android-glide

I have some issues when it comes to the scaling of my images that i load from a url.

They scale differently every second time. So at first they are loaded correctly. If i refresh the view. The image is scaled down. Then if i refresh another time. The view is scaled correctly again.

Anyone else that have had a similar problem with glide?

```
fun ImageView.loadUrl(key: String?, gameName: String?, width: Int?, height: Int?) {
    val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    GlideApp.with(context)
        .load(storage.getGameStorageReference(gameName!!, key!!))
        .into(this)
}
```

This is how the images are loaded in. Ignore the extra properties in the function. They are going to be used later.

**Correct way**

[image: Correct loaded image]

**Wrong way**

[image: Wrong loaded image]

**XML**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_feed_image_content_image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_feed_image_input"
    tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to this problem. Thanks to the following url https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1591

```
fun ImageView.loadUrl(key: String?, gameName: String?, width: Int?, height: Int?) {
    layout(0,0,0,0)
    val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    GlideApp.with(context)
        .load(storage.getGameStorageReference(gameName!!, key!!))
        .into(this)
}
```

So in other words i just called `imageview.layout(0,0,0,0)` to reset the imageview. This is done in `override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int)`